# Requiring administrator privileges when running from CD

Tags: c#, permissions, privileges, cd, directory.delete

I have a windows C# application which require administrator privileges.
I created an app.manifest modifying it adding

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

When I run it directly from my pc everything is ok, the OS prompt me the UAC and everything work fine.
Now, if I write all files into a CD (or iso image), some commands doesn't run with administrative privileges, causing errors.
In particular Directory.Delete, Directory.Copy (with recoursive parameter) don't work.

I also tried to wrap the default Delete method doing something like:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
public static void delete(string source, bool recursive)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(source))
    {
        Directory.Delete(source, recursive);
    }
}
```

But I get a "Request for principal permission failed." error.

Is there other I am missing? Why it should be different if running on a directory in my pc or running from cd?

Thanks,
Fabio

Comment: Can you delete files from CD? Directories?

Comment: What do you mean with "delete files from CD"?

Comment: I mean you cannot delete files/directories from compact disc last time I checked... Are you trying to delete from CD? btw no create as well

Comment: Yes, running my program from an iso image mounted (hope it will be the same running on a phisical cd) i can create a directory on my local machine. The problem is that I cannot delete or modify some files and deleting the directory if something happen

Comment: Yeah I understand, sorry cannot help you here...

Answer (score 0):

There is something called CAS (Code Access Security) in .NET. The CLR handles your program differently when it is from another source (so Local Intranet, Internet and Local Disk are handled differently)

When you are loading from CD, the settings would revert to a mode with less privileges.

You can find more on CAS [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You can request privileges by adding and configuring the [app.manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file.